# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, exceptionhandler

I am trying to implement [Primeface Exception Handler](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/exceptionHandler.xhtml)

My **faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2">

<!-- JSF and Spring are integrated -->
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>

</faces-config>
```

when I add the primefaces EL Resolver and factory in config, as follow, my tomcat fail start.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2">

<!-- JSF and Spring are integrated -->
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
    <el-resolver>
        org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>

<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
        org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>

</faces-config>
```

[image]

**any update ?**

**-----------EDIT----------**

I changes the tomcat version from 7.0.42 to 7.0.64, it showing me the following exception.

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly. 
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory
```

for detail in exception , please click [Exception Detail](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0w2jzfjdg5177bi/exception.txt?dl=0)

Comment: What do you have in the catalina.out logfile?

Comment: @GergelyBacso I just change to next version, now it showing the reason on console. plz see my Edit in above post. thanks

Comment: Strange. Do you have the jar containing PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory.class in your WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: @GergelyBacso I just upgrade primefaces from 4 to 5, issue resolved ! thanks for your precious time

Comment: Good news. Must have been really annoying to look for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was to **include the right version of PrimeFaces (5.0)**, previous versions did not contain this class.